# In Javascript / Jquery, is it possible to indirectly call an object method using a callback parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if the question is clear enough. I think an example is easier to understand. I want to do the following:

Instead of directly calling the object method, like this:

> ```
> $("#input").changed(function(){  
>     //do something  
> })
> ```

or this:

> ```
> $("#input").keyup(function(){  
>     //do something  
> })
> ```

I want to have a single function that can dinamically change the object's method that is being called, like this:

> ```
> function foobar(callback){
>     $("#input").callback(function(){  
>         //do something  
>     })
> }
>
> foobar("keyup")
> foobar("changed")
> ```

Comment: Look for "bracket notation", https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors, or you could use `on` which takes the event as a string.

Comment: @elclanrs I was putting jQuerys `on` into an answer but you beat me. Besides I think drakenation is confused about calling the action and changing the action.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of that but I bet it is a duplicate of something. :)

Comment: if you are looking to bind multiple events to the input control and have the same function called for each event then use $("#input").on("keyup changed", function() {...});

Comment: @user2321864 I actually want to write a small form validator with which I could easily change when each field is validated (onSubmit, onLoseFocus, onChange, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The methods are keys in a [Javascript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).  You can use the methods by name with a dot or within a string in square brackets:

```
$(selector).keyup()
```

or

```
$(selector)['keyup']()
```

So you could create a function like this:

```
function foobar(callback){
    $("#input")[callback](function(){  
        //do something  
    })
}
```

Although, it seems silly.

Comment: I'm a bit new to Javascript, and the language itself seems a bit silly for me. Having learned first C, then Python, then PHP, and now Javascript, JS "do what you want"-ish philosophy is a bit hard to wrap my head around. Also, so many anonymous functions! Anyway, thanks, case solved.

Comment: Thanks.  You should accept the answer as the solution if it fits.  Also, I agree, Javascript can be a little too flexible.